# Runtime Property Event Handler Binding

Tags: c#, events, properties, event-handling

I'm working on a class that is part of a library, let's call it Parent. Users of this library will use this Parent class by inheriting from it. 
Is there a way to get notified in Parent of any property change that occurs in Child?

```
public class Parent
{
  public Parent()
  {
   //Listen to changes in child properties and invoke MyHandler()
  }
  public void MyHandler(EventArgs args)
  {
  }
}

public class Child: Parent
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

So when the user sets a value to 'Name' I want an event handler in Parent to get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without the users of your library telling you somehow (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

At least I could only think of some dirty hacks via reflection (reading all properties via reflection and then e.g. polling them for changed values), which could cause (performance-)problems and so I would definitely recommend against such stuff and just document that the user must implement e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged` or your library will not work correctly.

Comment: I ended doing it using INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Thank you